# wicked_pdf page breaks splits one page into 45

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am working on a Rails project using wicked_pdf. Recently whenever I go to download a pdf, it prints it with the page I want, but with page breaks everywhere. Essentially this splits what should be 1 to 2 pages into 45. I have no idea where this problem is coming from.

Here are some files that may be important:

**Gemfile.lock**

```
wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.3)
```

**pdf.scss**

```
@media print {
  table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }

  .unbreakable {
    page-break-before: always !important;
    page-break-after: always !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
}
```

If there is anything else needed to solve the problem I can supply any info or code needed.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I have seen a thread recommended not to use `@media` also how many div elements have class unbreakable ? If you have 45 it's normal then..

Comment: It would be helpful to see the markup if possible, or at least the structure of it. Are there other styles that cause page-breaking? Also, wkhtmltopdf uses the screen stylesheet by default, so likely your print styles are being ignored.